# Catch every moment when user change his location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am using Google Map SDK. I want to catch every moment when user changes his location, maybe from CLLocationManagerDelegate. Can anyone say which method can execute previous job?

I tried to use   `func locationManager( _ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`  but it doesnot work well. When I run application, after 3-4 seconds this method call then If I change my location it doesnot do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `startUpdatingLocation()`?

Suppose that the below code is your `CLLocationManager`.

```
    lazy var locationMgt: CLLocationManager = {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        manager.distanceFilter = 1 // 1 meter
        
        manager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
#if os(iOS)
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
#endif
        manager.delegate = self
        return manager
    }()
```

Then ask for permission and start updating the location:

```
locationMgt.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

// you can call startUpdatingLocation() inside this function or call it right after requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    locationMgt.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Then your delegate implementation:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let last = locations.last else { return }
    // here user's last location is available.
}
```